# How to show my Facebook page questionn poll in my website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I spent a couple of hours reading [Facebook developers docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs) and trying to figure out if there is a way to show my Facebook page question poll in my website somehow - I still don't have an answer...
Does anyone know if it's even possible?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but not trivial.

If you just want to display the question, answers and current results, you'll need to:

- Gain a valid access token for the profile that hosts the question with `user_questions` permission.
- Make a call to [the API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/question/) at `https://graph.facebook.com/PROFILE_ID/questions` using this access token, and
- Parse the JSON object that is returned and display this on your site.